# Android: NavigationView enviar información / detectar elementos del header

Tags: java, android, navigationview, navigation-drawer

Tengo un NavigationView el cual está compuesto por un header y un menu app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header_user"
app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu". Sin embargo al tratar de acceder a los elementos del header (drawer_header_usar) y enviarle los datos de la persona recién logeada obtengo lo siguiente:

`exception: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference`

Siempre he accedido a los elementos mediante el id, sin embargo, para los elementos de mi header me retorna siempre nulo. Pienso que es porque está dentro de otra vista, pero no es como un objeto que puedo acceder a sus elementos con un punto "." debe haber alguna forma estaría agradecido.

```
            textViewIdHeaderUser = findViewById(R.id.textViewIdHeaderUser);
            textViewNombreHeaderUser = findViewById(R.id.textViewNombreHeaderUser);
            textViewApellidoHeaderUser = findViewById(R.id.textViewApellidoHeaderUser);
            textViewCelularHeaderUser = findViewById(R.id.textViewCelularHeaderUser);
            textViewCorreorHeaderUser = findViewById(R.id.textViewCorreorHeaderUser);

            textViewIdHeaderUser.setText(String.valueOf(empleado.getId()));
            textViewNombreHeaderUser.setText(empleado.getNombre());
            textViewApellidoHeaderUser.setText(empleado.getApellido());
            textViewCelularHeaderUser.setText(empleado.getCelular());
            textViewCorreorHeaderUser.setText(empleado.getCorreo());
```

````
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.fullchamba.entidad.Empleado;
import com.example.fullchamba.fragment.InicioFragment;
import com.example.fullchamba.fragment.LogInFragment;
import com.example.fullchamba.fragment.SignUpFragment;
import com.example.fullchamba.fragment.TareaFragment;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

public class PrincipalActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    NavigationView navigationView;

    FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;

    Empleado empleado;

    TextView textViewIdHeaderUser;
    TextView textViewNombreHeaderUser;
    TextView textViewApellidoHeaderUser;
    TextView textViewCelularHeaderUser;
    TextView textViewCorreorHeaderUser;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal);

        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);

        try {

            int id = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("id");
            String nombre = getIntent().getExtras().getString("nombre");
            String apellido = getIntent().getExtras().getString("apellido");
            String celular = getIntent().getExtras().getString("celular");
            String correo = getIntent().getExtras().getString("correo");
            String clave = getIntent().getExtras().getString("clave");
            int estado = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("estado");
            int cargo_id = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("cargo_id");

            empleado = new Empleado(id, nombre, apellido, celular, correo, clave, estado, cargo_id);

            textViewIdHeaderUser = findViewById(R.id.textViewIdHeaderUser);
            textViewNombreHeaderUser = findViewById(R.id.textViewNombreHeaderUser);
            textViewApellidoHeaderUser = findViewById(R.id.textViewApellidoHeaderUser);
            textViewCelularHeaderUser = findViewById(R.id.textViewCelularHeaderUser);
            textViewCorreorHeaderUser = findViewById(R.id.textViewCorreorHeaderUser);

            textViewIdHeaderUser.setText(String.valueOf(empleado.getId()));
            textViewNombreHeaderUser.setText(empleado.getNombre());
            textViewApellidoHeaderUser.setText(empleado.getApellido());
            textViewCelularHeaderUser.setText(empleado.getCelular());
            textViewCorreorHeaderUser.setText(empleado.getCorreo());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Exception: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.w("exception", e.getMessage());
        }

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, (R.string.open), (R.string.close));
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();

        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_principal, new TareaFragment());
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.inicio) {
            fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_principal, new TareaFragment());
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.perfil) {
            fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_principal, new SignUpFragment());
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.tarea) {
            fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_principal, new LogInFragment());
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.dashboard) {
            fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_principal, new TareaFragment());
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.salir) {
            fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_principal, new InicioFragment());
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
        return false;

    }

} ```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

debes obtener la referencia a tus textViews desde el headerLayout de tu navigation view, prueba con este código

```
NavigationView navView= findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
View headerLayout=navView.getHeaderView(0)
textViewIdHeaderUser = headerLayout.findViewById(R.id.textViewIdHeaderUser);
textViewNombreHeaderUser = headerLayout.findViewById(R.id.textViewNombreHeaderUser);
textViewApellidoHeaderUser = headerLayout.findViewById(R.id.textViewApellidoHeaderUser);
textViewCelularHeaderUser = headerLayout.findViewById(R.id.textViewCelularHeaderUser);
textViewCorreorHeaderUser = headerLayout.findViewById(R.id.textViewCorreorHeaderUser);
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Me ha funcionado! Sorry que no te pueda dejar puntos.

Comment: Me alegra que te funcionara, saludos!